# Django-RQ having a hard time adding items to Django Model

Tags: python, django, redis, python-rq, django-rq

I'm using django-rq to setup background tasks using Redis. Redis is working great and the code is sending the request to Redis - but it is throwing an exception.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeremyenglert/Documents/Sites/showzone/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 1003, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/Users/jeremyenglert/Documents/Sites/showzone/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 893, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/Users/jeremyenglert/Documents/Sites/showzone/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 254, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/Users/jeremyenglert/Documents/Sites/showzone/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 222, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
  File "./api/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class PlayerProfile(models.Model):
  File "/Users/jeremyenglert/Documents/Sites/showzone/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Users/jeremyenglert/Documents/Sites/showzone/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/jeremyenglert/Documents/Sites/showzone/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/jeremyenglert/Documents/Sites/showzone/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/jeremyenglert/Documents/Sites/showzone/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 64, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings
```

Here is a simplified version of the code.

```
# views.py
class PlayerProfileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def update_all_profiles(self, request, pk=None):
        update_player_profiles.delay(PlayerProfile)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```
# update_player_profiles.py
@job
def update_player_profiles(model):
    a_long_running_request_for_a_csv_file()
    a_long_running_task_to_process_data()
    a_long_running_task_to_save_the_data_to_a_django_model()
```

How can I make it so django-rq can interact with the django models? Or is there a different problem at play?